# Induced Matrix norm of ||$\alpha$I||

Tags: matrix-norms

If I have a matrix A = $\alpha$I where I is the identity matrix and a is some non-zero real number.

How would I go about taking the induced matrix norm of it?

I'm leaning towards using the submultiplicativity property, but I'm just not really sure how to approach this one, new to norms ;p. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the submultiplicativity is needed here. Indeed, an induced matrix norm is by definition, shaped as
$$\||M\|| = \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$$
where $M$ is squared matrix, i.e. mapping vectors from a vector space $V$ to vectors of $V$, and $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $V$. Now, by homogeneity of the norm $\|\cdot \|$ we have that $\|\alpha I x\|=|\alpha | \|Ix\|=|\alpha | \|x\|$, and therefore, if $A=\alpha I$, for every $x\neq 0, x \in V$, we have
$$\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\frac{|\alpha| \|x\|}{\|x\|}=|\alpha|,$$
implying $\||A\||=|\alpha|$.

Comment: But isn't the property

||Ax|| $\le$ ||A|| * ||x||, how can we assume that it will be equal?

Comment: $\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Mx\|}{\|x\|} = \inf\{\lambda >0 \mid \|Ax\|\leq \lambda \|x\|, \forall x\}$, anyway, as stated in my post, $\|\alpha I x\|= |\alpha| \|IIx\|=|\alpha| \|x\|$ for every $x$, so $|\alpha| \|x\|\leq \|\alpha I x \|\leq |\alpha| \|x\|$ for all $x$.

Comment: Starting from $\|Ax\|\leq \|A\| \|x\|$, if $x\neq 0$ then $\|x\|> 0$ so, we have $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\leq \|A\|$ for all $x\neq 0$. Taking the supremum on the latter inequality shows $\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\leq \|A\|$. For the reverse inequality: since $x\mapsto \|Ax\|$ is a continuous function on the compact set $\{x:\|x\|=1\}$, it attains its maximum. This maximum is precisely $\|A\|$.